# Lacking the amount of energy that needs for a good workout at gym

Tags: workout, gym, energy

I daily plan to workout and hit at the gym but I come home fully exhausted. I lack the amount of energy that needs for a good workout at gym. How can I cope up with this? Anything that could keep me energetic and motivated to exercise when I come back home?

Comment: Don't go home. just go from work to a gym/outdoor Park/whatsoever and train. If I got home after work I won't do anything besides eating/resting/sleeping.

Comment: Ever try working out the first thing in the morning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Don't go home**

Stop at the gym before going home. If you go home, your mind tells you your work day is done, and you give yourself permission to crash. If you go to the gym before going home, you're still in the "Get things done" mindset.

**Change your timing**

You might find it easier to go before work, or later in the evening after you've had dinner and would normally be watching TV.

**Be less ambitious**

If work leaves you too tired for a long, intense workout, then find an shorter workout you can do at home. Adjustable dumbbells, kettlebells, and calisthenics are all compact ways to do strength training at home, or you can try running outdoors, jump rope, or yoga. And if you are efficient, you can do a very intensive workout in half an hour and still get decent improvement, or at least maintain if you are in excellent shape already.

**Just Do Saturdays**

If you don't have the time and energy to exercise at all during the week, exercising only on the weekend can at least keep you from losing much fitness until you can change your lifestyle and exercise more often.

Comment: Thanks Karen...you have given me a good start. Your 1st and 3rd point seems to be very effective.